# Excel VBA: Function applying to individual sheets

Tags: vba, excel, calculated-columns

I have a large number of worksheets that have the same layout, column `G6:G38` is the years and Column `H6:H38` is the corresponding amounts paid. I tried to create a simple formula that I could use in all the sheets that searches through these columns and sums the amounts in a given year. 
This is the function I wrote into a module:

```
Public Function TPaid(Year As Integer)
Application.Volatile
Dim x As Integer
x = 6
Do Until x = 38
    If Range("G" & x).Value = Year Then
    TPaid = TPaid + Range("H" & x).Value
    End If
    x = x + 1
Loop
End Function
```

After inserting the formula into individual cells on all the worksheets, I'm finding that each time I enter the formula, it causes all other uses of the same formula on the other worksheets to display that most recent calculation. How can I make the formula only apply to the sheet its entered into?

Example: on `sheet1` in cell `A1` I imputed `=Tpaid(2013)`. then on `sheet2` in cell `A1` I imputed `=Tpaid(2013)`. After hitting enter on `sheet2` the amount displayed is correct, but now the amount in `sheet1` has changed to display the same amount as in `sheet2`, which is incorrect.

Comment: You could easily do that by qualifying the `Range` with the sheet object: `Application.Caller.Parent.Range("H" & x).Value`, but you shouldn't. Instead you should pass the summing range into the function as a parameter and remove the `Application.Volatile`. Better yet, just use the [`SUMIF` function](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) Excel already has.

Answer (score 1):

As GSerg said, this can be done a couple of ways, the best of which is `=SUMIF(G6:G38,2013,H6:H38)`.

Otherwise,

```
Public Function TPaid(Year As Integer)
  Application.Volatile
  Dim x As Integer, obj as Object
  With Application.Caller.Parent
    For x = 6 to 38
      If .Range("G" & x).Value = Year Then TPaid = TPaid + .Range("H" & x).Value
    Next
  End With
End Function
```